# Get the absolute path of the class file for a method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, path

I have a code example, that browse my workspace and picks every method in every class.
My intention is to print out the absolute path of the method, but I can´t figure out how do to it.

Something like `method.getAbsolutePath()` is not existed.

My Code:

```
IPackageFragment[] packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();
for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {
    for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
        IType[] allTypes = unit.getAllTypes();
        for (IType type : allTypes) {
            IMethod[] methods = type.getMethods();
            for (IMethod method : methods) {
                //System.out.println(MyMethodPath);
                //here is want to print the path
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: So... You want to print the full package name, followed by the class, followed by the method name?

Comment: Not to confuse: I want to print out the path of the CLASS where the method is in.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the class with [IMethod.getClassFile](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIMethod.html), which can then be used to get the absolute path using [IClassFile.getPath](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIClassFile.html), or more to the point:

```
System.out.println(method.getClassFile().getPath().toString());
```

Comment: For some reason this returns always null for me. For every method in my workspace

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need, of not comment me:

```
System.getProperty ("user.dir");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this prints out the path of eclipse, but not of the class in my workspace.